# How to add a space to every two characters in a data frame

Tags: r, regex

I have a big data frame where I need to add space after every two character.
For example (First I have just one column x 2 rows):

```
          V1
AAAAGGCCCCCC
00AACGAACCAA
```

What I want is (now its going to be 6 columns x 2 rows):

```
V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6      
AA AA GG CC CC CC
00 AA CG AA CC AA
```

Does anyone has a idea?

Comment: Try `strsplit(df1$V1, "(?<=..)", perl = TRUE)`

Answer (score 3):

Add a comma to the end of each pair of character and then split at that comma

```
data.frame(do.call(rbind, strsplit(gsub("(..)", "\\1,", d$V1), ",")))
#  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6
#1 AA AA GG CC CC CC
#2 00 AA CG AA CC AA
```

**DATA**

```
d = data.frame(V1 = c("AAAAGGCCCCCC", "00AACGAACCAA"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another option with `strsplit` with a regex lookaround to split after every 2 characters

```
do.call(rbind, strsplit(df1$V1, "(?<=..)", perl = TRUE))
#  [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
#[1,] "AA" "AA" "GG" "CC" "CC" "CC"
#[2,] "00" "AA" "CG" "AA" "CC" "AA"
```

Wrap with `data.frame` if we need a `data.frame` output

---

Or another option is `read.fwf` and specify the `widths` argument

```
read.fwf(file = textConnection(df1$V1), widths = rep(2, 6))
#  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6
#1 AA AA GG CC CC CC
#2 00 AA CG AA CC AA
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(V1 = c("AAAAGGCCCCCC", "00AACGAACCAA")),
        class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Answer (score 2):

Just a doodle in `tidyr` (using *@d.b's* data):

```r
tidyr::separate(df1, V1, c("V1","V2","V3","V4","V5","V6"), 
                         sep = seq(2, nchar(as.character(df1$V1[1])), by = 2))

 #    V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V5
 # 1: AA AA GG CC CC CC
 # 2: 00 AA CG AA CC AA
```

Answer (score 1):

An other base R solution, using `substr` and a bit of counting :

```
sapply(plouf,function(vec){
  sapply(1:(nchar(vec)/2),function(x){substr(vec, 2*x-1, 2*x)})
}) %>% 
  t() %>%
  as.data.frame()%>%
  `colnames<-`(paste0("V",1:(nchar(plouf[1])/2) ))%>%
  `rownames<-`(NULL)

  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6
1 AA AA GG CC CC CC
2 00 AA CG AA CC AA
```

---

data

```
plouf <- c("AAAAGGCCCCCC","00AACGAACCAA")
```